# ListView item images misplacing and disappear sometimes while scroll up/down in Xamrin.Form

Tags: c#, xamarin, data-binding, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have read this post but I really didn't get much.

[Recyclerview Images Misplacing and disappear while scrolling up/down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42943593/recyclerview-images-misplacing-and-disappear-while-scrolling-up-down)

When I scroll Up/Down, some image misplace and some image disappear. I have review my code and given enough time to get rid of the problem. But unfortunately I didn't find any way to resolve this.

Can anybody please guide me? I check with iOS.

EmployeeResultsPage

```
<ListView x:Name="EmployeeResultsListView"
          ItemsSource="{Binding EmployeeResults}"
          RowHeight="200"
          IsPullToRefreshEnabled="true"
          RefreshCommand="{Binding RefreshDataCommand}"
          IsRefreshing="{Binding IsRefreshingData, Mode=OneWay}"
          ItemAppearing="Employee_ItemAppearing"
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <local:EmployeeResultViewCell />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

EmployeeResultsPage.CS

```
private void Employee_ItemAppearing(object sender, ItemVisibilityEventArgs e)
{
    var itemObject = e.Item as ExtendedEmployee;
    if (_viewModel.EmployeeResults.Last() == itemObject)
    {
        if (_viewModel.LoadEmployee.CanExecute(null))
        {
            _viewModel.LoadEmployee.Execute(null);
        }
    }
}
```

EmployeeResultViewModel

```
[ImplementPropertyChanged]
public class EmployeeResultsViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private async Task LoadEmployee()
    {
        EmployeeResults = GetDataUsingAPI(); //15 records per call
    }

    public ObservableRangeCollection<ExtendedEmployee> EmployeeResults { get; set; }

    public string EmployeePhotoUrl { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
}
```

EmployeeResultViewCell

```
<ViewCell.View>
    <Grid RowSpacing="0" ColumnSpacing="0" VerticalOptions="Center" HeightRequest="150">
        <Image x:Name="EmployeeImage" Grid.Column="0" HeightRequest="150" WidthRequest="150"
        Source="{Binding EmployeePhotoUrl}" />
        <Label Text="{Binding EmployeeName}" FontSize="18" TextColor="Grey"/>
    </Grid>
</ViewCell.View>
```

CS File

```
public partial class EmployeeResultViewCell : CustomViewCell
{
    public EmployeeResultViewCell()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnBindingContextChanged()
    {
        base.OnBindingContextChanged();
        var employee = (BindingContext as ExtendedEmployee);
    }
}
```

Rendering Code

```
public class CustomViewCellRenderer: ViewCellRenderer
{
    public override UITableViewCell GetCell(Cell item, UITableViewCell reusableCell, UITableView tv)
    {
        var cell = base.GetCell(item, reusableCell, tv);
        cell.SeparatorInset = UIEdgeInsets.Zero;

        if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(8, 0))
        {
            cell.PreservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = false;
            cell.LayoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets.Zero;
        }
        cell.SelectedBackgroundView = new UIView
        {
            BackgroundColor = UIColor.FromRGBA(233, 21, 80, 18)
        };
        return cell;
    }
}
```

Comment: `EmployeeResults = GetDataUsingAPI();` this will replace all the items not add new items. So is this causing your issue?

Comment: @LandLu-MSFT No, It manages list. It get 5 items in each api call. Everytime it appends items from next counter. Here, misplace means it just misplace images. It doesn't misplace other things like name etc. Please suggest.

Comment: @LandLu-MSFT I have added my rendering page code. Can you please look into? That will be really helpfull to me.

Comment: I test your code in my side with local images, but I can't reproduce your issue. Also I modify this `GetDataUsingAPI()` to my own add items method. Can you provide a sample to help me reproduce your issue?